# Selenium webdriver.get() method is not opening specified URL

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use chromedriver.exe to do some web scraping / automation -- my code is below

```
from selenium import webdriver 
browser = webdriver.Chrome('MY_PATH')
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
browser.close()
```

Once I execute the "browser" variable then a blank google browser opens, but when I try to execute the .get() function this is the error I receive:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-0ba0932650bf> in <module>
----> 1 browser.get("https://www.google.com")
      2 browser.close()

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in get(self, url)
    331         Loads a web page in the current browser session.
    332         """
--> 333         self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
    334 
    335     @property

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py in execute(self, driver_command, params)
    319         response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
    320         if response:
--> 321             self.error_handler.check_response(response)
    322             response['value'] = self._unwrap_value(
    323                 response.get('value', None))

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py in check_response(self, response)
    240                 alert_text = value['alert'].get('text')
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

WebDriverException: Message: chrome not reachable
  (Session info: chrome=85.0.4183.102)
```

Any thoughts / feedback / suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Once crosscheck the ChromeDriver version and Chrome version. [Link](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection)

Answer (score 0):

ChromeDriver and Chrome browser aren't compatible, maybe you might have the latest Chrome browser but you don't have the latest chromeDriver - [here](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) you can download it - it's ChromeDriver 86.0.4240.22

Answer (score 0):

first of all, make sure of the followings:

1. make sure chromedriver exist in your 'PATH' environment variables
2. check out your chromedriver version matches the chrome version you are using
   -you can check your chrome version from help--> about Google Chrome

   - then download compatible Chromedriver version from [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

This is caused due to the wrong chrome driver to the certain chrome version you have.
You can find the chromedriver here [Chrome Driver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)
Or you could let webdriver manager handle all your issues by doing

```
pip install webdriver-manager in command prompt
```

Than simply using.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- **Remember to pass the path to the `executable_path` keyword argument**
- Have matching version of Chrome and Chrome Driver

```py
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_driver_path = '/home/aahnik/Downloads/apps/chromedriver'
# path to where chrome driver executable is installed.
# make sure to have matching versions of Chrome and Chrome Driver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)

driver.get("https://aahnik.github.io/")
```